# What java type corresponds to <input type="file">?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to upload files to a mysql database.

Here's my form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.themyleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<title>User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please enter the following to upload the file.</h1>
     <form action="#" th:action="@{/uploadToDB}" th:object="${doc}" method="post">
        <p>Author: <input type="text" th:field="*{author}" /></p>
        <p>Publication date: <input type="text" th:field="*{pubDate}" /></p>
        <p>Title: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></p>
        <p>Editor: <input type="text" th:field="*{editor}" /></p>
        <p>Content type: <input type="text" th:field="*{contentType}" /></p>
        <p>Size: <input type="text" th:field="*{size}" /></p>
        <p>Content: <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" th:field="*{content}"></input></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"></input>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

These values are then set to my bean *Document* :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Component
public class Document implements Serializable {

    private String author;
    private String pubDate;
    private String title;
    private String uploadDate;
    private String editor;
    private String id;
    private String contentType;
    private String size;
    private Blob content;

   //setters and getters
```

Now the problem I am facing is I don't know the type implied by the `<input type="file">`. It generates an error when I set `content` to `Blob`, which is the type I am looking for to insert into my database.

I previously used `String` but it doesn't seem to be the good type either. I can insert it into my database. But I can't retrieve the file from my database to display it or download it afterwards.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Try byte [].  Once you read the contents into a String you can do what you wish with it.

Comment: Thanks. Gonna try this.*

Comment: Good call, I can directly use `byte[]`, and do this `PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql); ps.setBytes(8, d.getContentFromForm());`. I guess this will solve my problems when I try to retrieve the file. Thanks.

Comment: I'm very glad to have helped.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

@duffymo answered it. Simply use byte[].

Answer (score 2):

Use `enctype` Attribute in Form tag .

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/uploadToDB}" th:object="${doc}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and use `byte[]` Because Database like Mysql and Oracle Stores a Multimedia data in the form of binary format .  and uses `byte[]` array for Storing the Data .